# coffeescript return function callback acting strange

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

let's say i have a simple function like that:

```
foo ->  
  User.findById someId, (err, user) ->
    return "hello #{user.name}"
```

coffeescript [translate](http://js2coffee.org/) it to that:

```
foo(function() {
  return User.findById(someId, function(err, user) {
   return "hello " + user.name;
  });
});
```

so there are 2 returns here from some reason, but i just want to return the "hello" after the callback.

the only way i found not to return a function when i use it is by closing it with a `return` (that is a weird workaround). so:

```
foo ->  
  User.findById someId, (err, user) ->
    return "hello #{user.name}"
  return
```

will translate into:

```
foo(function() {
  User.findById(someId, function(err, user) {
    return "hello " + user.name;
  });
});
```

is there a better way to do that other than closing a function with a `return` key?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, but the Coffeescript translator is just doing what you're telling it to do.  Your first example says, "The function 'foo' should call the function 'User.findById' and pass it the value of 'someId' and another function, which takes two parameters 'err' and 'user', and returns a string."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine, that's how Coffeescript works, it always returns the last expression of a function unless you return `undefined` with an empty `return`, or something else.

Comment: but this is not the last line of function, there is another line inside the callback

Comment: That isn't the last line, since it's a callback. The last line of the function is `User.findById...`. Coffeescript does this for **every** function, the callback as well.

Comment: I should probably say "expression" instead of "line". It's not a big deal, and they way your cancelling is correct.

Comment: i see. so isn't a way to wrap it with another word? i feel like `return` is wrong to use as a closer to a function. something like `end` should be instead

Comment: I agree, I'm a fan of [LiveScript](http://livescript.net/), where you can simply avoid it like `!->`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return `"hello #{user.name}"` from the anonymous function and return nothing from `foo`, it's sufficient to do:

```
foo = ->  
  User.findById someId, (err, user) ->
    "hello #{user.name}"
  return
```

Note that most likely, the return value of the callback (the anonymous function) won't be accessible to you. The callback is called by the `findById` function, and this function most likely discards the callback's return value.

Also, in principle, it doesn't matter if a function returns a weird value, as long as it's never used. You only need to put explicit `return` or `undefined` on the last line of a function body if you want to create a really clean API.

Comment: this why i'm saying weird. it's not a `return` at the end. it's a closer for the function and should be `end` instead. the return is for the inner function

Comment: @sagivo: The `return` in the callback function is not needed, it will be assumed anyway.

Comment: the problem is not with that, the problem is with the second return (the one that close the function)

Comment: There's no "end" in CoffeeScript. In CoffeeScript, the end of functions are marked by either a "dedent" (decrease in indentation) or possibly reaching the end of the file.

Comment: I understand, I think the point of this answer is to prove that it is not a problem if a function returns something as long as you always discard the value.

Comment: if you don't close the first function with this `return` key, it is a problem because you'll get back something else instead the inner return. that force you closing function with return key (and that's what i don't like on coffeescript) :\

Comment: @sagivo: I think you're missing the point. `return` is not a keyword to close the function as `end` in Ruby. `return` is the **same** as in vanilla JavaScript. Coffeescript will `return` automatically, but if you put `return` explicitly then it won't. The indentation is what determines where the function ends.

Comment: to explicitly call `return` in order not to return is sick :)

Comment: LOL. That's the part where I agree. But think of it this way: vanilla JavaScript returns `undefined` implicitly, so if you `return` nothing, it is the same thing.